I can't build an android application with the creation of flet using flutter, I've set everything up, but I can't figure out what the problem is?
the python code itself works, but the Android app is not being created, Android Studio is also installed and the sdk, along with the flutter module, are downloaded and added to the Path
C:\Users\New\Desktop\pro\WN>flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies in ..... (4.2s)
+ archive 3.5.0
+ args 2.5.0
+ checked_yaml 2.0.3
+ cli_util 0.4.1
+ collection 1.18.0
+ crypto 3.0.3
+ flutter_launcher_icons 0.13.1
+ image 4.1.7
+ json_annotation 4.9.0
+ meta 1.14.0
+ path 1.9.0
+ petitparser 6.0.2
+ source_span 1.10.0
+ string_scanner 1.2.0
+ term_glyph 1.2.1
+ typed_data 1.3.2
+ xml 6.5.0
+ yaml 3.1.2
Changed 18 dependencies in ..!

C:\Users\New\Desktop\pro\WN>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 3.19.6 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 54e66469a9 (12 days ago), 2024-04-17 13:08:03 -0700
    • Engine revision c4cd48e186
    • Dart version 3.3.4
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: G:\ПО\Android_Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0--11185874)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9.4)
    • Visual Studio at G:\ПО\MS
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.9.34714.143
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
    • Android Studio at G:\ПО\Android_Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0--11185874)

[√] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.86.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.63
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 124.0.2478.51

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

C:\Users\New\Desktop\pro\WN>flet build apk --verbose
Flutter bootstrap directory: C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_rQEKJuuLj6
Additional Flutter dependencies:
{}
Creating Flutter bootstrap project...OK
Customizing app icons and splash images...OK
Generating app icons...
Run subprocess: ['C:\\flutter\\bin\\dart', 'run', 'flutter_launcher_icons']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\flet.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\cli.py", line 83, in main
    args.handler(args)
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\commands\build.py", line 599, in handle
    icons_result = self.run(
                   ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\commands\build.py", line 828, in run
    r = subprocess.run(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32



Generating app icons...
Run subprocess: ['C:\flutter\bin\dart', 'run', 'flutter_launcher_icons']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in run_code
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\flet.exe_main.py", line 7, in 
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\cli.py", line 83, in main
args.handler(args)
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\commands\build.py", line 599, in handle
icons_result = self.run(
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flet\cli\commands\build.py", line 828, in run
r = subprocess.run(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32    - I dont now
I expected the application to assemble. Path variables are all configured. Помогите пожалуйста.
